# Changing all values in one column of Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas Data Frame with 22 columns, I want to modify all the values in the column 'Result'.

In my file the values from the result column are strings in the form 'W (+3)', I want to extract the integer, basically the thing inside the paranthesis.

```
a[a.find("(")+1:a.find(")")]
```

I just use the find function and index the string. But how do I apply this to all the values in column 'Result'. I suposse I could iterate through with a for loop, is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.extract` with a regex pattern

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Result": [ 'W (+3)' ]})
print(df["Result"].str.extract(r"\((.*?)\)"))
```

**Output:**

```
0    +3
Name: Result, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you. basically just added df['Result']= df["Result"].str.extract(r"\((.*?)\)")

Comment: `(r"((.*?))")` will not get content inside the parenthesis. Is that ok?

Comment: It works fine, thank you. I just assigned the new column.

Answer (score 0):

There is an apply function: a['Results'].apply(lambda x: ... ), it's faster than looping through your dataframe